# Calculated column will return weird results if the fields involved contain null values

Tags: 2013, development, calculated-column

I have 2 columns inside my list:-

1. [Live/Active Date]. of type **Date**.
2. [Contract Length (month)] . of type **number**, which does not allow decimals.

now based on the above 2 fields, i want to calculate the expiry date, by adding the contract length in month to the live/active date. so i created a calculated column with this formula:-

```
=DATE(YEAR([Live/Active Date]),(MONTH([Live/Active Date])+[Contract Length (month)]),DAY([Live/Active Date]))
```

this will work if both fields [Live/Active Date] & [Contract Length (month)] do have values, but if one of them or both of them are null then instead of getting null calculated result, i will get weird results. For example if the [live/Active date] is null while [Contract Length (month)] = 12, i was expecting to get null for the calculated field, while i got this `30/12/3800`!! . i am searching for a solution to have my calculated column = null, if any of the 2 fields involved in the formula are null. i do not want to use defualt values or set the fields as required. so is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A null or empty date is typically treated as 12/31/1899.

Try something like this:

```
=IF( OR(ISBLANK([Live/Active Date] ), ISBLANK([Contract Length (month)]) ),
"missing data", yourEquationHere )
```